# Symfony2 - handle HTTP/Entity user access restrictions

Tags: security, symfony, http

We have a little discussion in my team how to handle http restriction in our app.

In our app a user can create products. So we have routes like `/products` and `/product/1/show` to list and show products of a user. A user can not see products of another user. The app uses a REST endpoint to fetch the data. The API call looks like this `/api/product/1/` to fetch a single product.

We have more routes/API endpoint for other kinds of entities.

The question is how to protect a route/API request against other users?

We have two solutions:

1. use the firewall and voters. The voter gets the current url `/product/1/show` and checks if given product is owned by the current logged in user.
2. use a voter without the firewall: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html
3. use the role system: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/annotations

I prefer solution 1. because all information we need (who is the owner of the product) still exist. We only need to fetch the entity and do a check. 
In solution 2. we have to spread the voter logic over several controllers.

Are there recommendations or experiences on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If i have to choose between those three it would be 1. But i suggest a different route. I assume that the digit 1 in /product/1/show stands for the user number? If that is the case i suggest that you make new routes without the numbers e.g. /my-products/show . The controller must then use the id of the currently logged in user.

Comment: The `1` stands for the products-id